# Exception propagation in spring Boot - microservice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

How to propagate exceptions from one microservice to another in the spring Boot application.

Ex: when we make a get rest call then we would expect some valid response. Let's say we are expecting a response of type Long. But if there is An exception thrown from the other microservice then how it should be caught and handled in calling the microservice?

Currently, we are getting a deserialization issue in the token objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`@ControllerAdvice`](https://medium.com/@jovannypcg/understanding-springs-controlleradvice-cd96a364033f) to catch different types of exception which would occur in one microservice, and would send 5XX response code to inform other service that it was not able to process the request correctly, asit is considered a good practise to talk in response codes. PFB an example code.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MicroserviceExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler({ UserNotFoundException.class, ContentNotAllowedException.class })
    public final ResponseEntity handleException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        String errorMessage = ex.getMessage();
        return ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                .status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
                .body(errorMessage);
```

*But if it required for your microservices to send the whole stack trace instead of just the message, then use below code to convert the stacktrace as a string and send it instead of `ex.getMessage()`*

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to propagate exception from one microservice to another in spring
>   Boot application.

Microservices are talking to each other over the network and usually it is HTTP(s). So, at the boundaries of the microservices, the exceptions will get converted as standard HTTP error codes (for client error `4XX`, for server errors `5XX` and so on) and optional error message(s). When you invoke an upstream service, if the response is not a success (`HTTP2XX`), your consumer service just need to look for the agreed up on error codes / messages and translate it into meaningful actions(meaningful for the consumer service).

I would suggest you to read https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html

Answer (score 0):

What we do is:

- Define an entity `ErrorInfo` and an exception handler class. Also, we have an `ErrorCode` which relates exception with status code. And an exception `ServiceException` using `ErrorCode`. Isolate these classes into a shared library for all services.
- In the dependent service, when an exception is thrown, depending on where and when, we define a dedicated `ErrorCode` with a certain status code for it and attach it to the `ServiceException`, and throw.
- In the exception handler, use `ErrorCode` and other related fields in `ServiceException`, we define an `ErrorInfo` with error cause, details, messages and so on, and return `ResponseEntity` with body of `ErrorInfo` and status code 4xx/5xx, as per `ErrorCode`.
- In the caller service(where the same library is used), when status code is 4xx/5xx, parse/deserialize body as `ErrorInfo` and construct the same exception. And throw it for the same exception handler in the library to return as `ErrorInfo` to Front End.
- FE/other client can always expect `ErrorInfo` as a standard template when anything goes wrong. It can contain fields like `message`/`cause`/... so i18n can be done easily as well.